# Build definition xxxx does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I intergated TFS2005 to TFS2010 successfully and I have to use Visual Studio 2005 to edit and build the project using build types. These build types were declared before the integration. I need to use one of them.
But when I try to build a project the following error message appears:

TF215016: The build definition xxxx does not exist. Specify a valid build definition and try again.

I have no idea how could solve this. Google didn't find anything useful.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot edit TFS 2010 build definitions from VS 2005, you need to have either Team Explorer 2010 or VS 2010 installed and edit the definition from there, it's one of the few bits of TFS that isn't compatible between TFS / VS versions.

If you're using the upgrade template for your builds then you will still be calling out to a tfsbuild.proj to control what gets built and this can be edited in VS 2005.